# Error with a prepared statement with named placeholders in PHP with mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am getting these errors on my webpage with this code

```
Notice: Undefined variable: dbh in /home/danu2_cj3/public_html/lists.php on line 14

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/danu2_cj3/public_html/lists.php on line 14
```

This is the php code i am using and line 14 is the 4th line in this code

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$member = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name
    FROM lists
    WHERE member_id = :member_id ');
$sth->bindValue(':member_id', $member, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
?>
```

I am trying to show an array of a bunch of rows where one of the fields in those rows is supposed to match the member_id for the person logged into the session

here is the whole code for the page (top.php and bottom.php are just layout pages)

```
<?php include ('top.php')?>
<h1>My Profile </h1>
<a href="lists.php">My Lists</a> | <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></br>
</br>
Please select list to view/delete
<?php include ("connect.php")?>
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$member = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name
    FROM lists
    WHERE member_id = :member_id ');
$sth->bindValue(':member_id', $member, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
?>

<?php include ('bottom.php')?>
```

Here is my connect.php file

```
<?php
$username = "mydb";
$password = "mydb";
$hostname = "host"; 

//connection to the database
$dbh = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
 or die("Unable to connect to database");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("mydb",$dbh) 
  or die("Could not select database");
?>
```

Comment: From that error message, you've not defined `$dbh`. Where are you initialising it?

Comment: I dont really know, where should i be initialising it? and how do i go about that?

Comment: You should probably add the whole of your code into your question - the error's being caused by something that isn't included here.

Comment: i have edited it there now to show the rest!

Comment: You need to check connect.php. That should be setting up `$dbh` as the database connection, and isn't.

Comment: ok so now i am only getting the fatal error for the function prepare? connect.php added there to the original post

Comment: You're using mysql_* to create the connection; but PDO to do the querying. Try setting up your connection using Fabio's answer, and see if that works better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably add `connection` to database or check if it is correctly set in `connect.php`

```
try 
{
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} 
catch (PDOException $e) 
{
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

[**DOCUMENTATION HERE**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)